# Design pattern for storing settings in c#

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have the following application which interfaces with a custom device. The application is used to program the device.

My application can read settings from the device, and program settings to the device. So that would mean, two sets of settings; one set of settings which are currently in the device, and one which are entered by the user via the application.

There are differnt device types, all with some settings in common and some device specific.

I was thinking about two classes, with both the complete set of settings. Both using singleton so I can easily acces all setting through my whole project. But this does not feel right, any tips on this situation

Comment: Maybe it's me, but the question is a little unclear. "There are different device types ..." - this makes it sound like you want more than 2 classes ... or can you only have 1 device type at any given time? ... or is device type one of the settings?

Comment: I have lets say, 4 different devices which I should be able to program using this tool. They have like 75% of the settings in common, and 25% of the settings is unique for the device. If a device is connected the settings are read, and if the user enters settings, they should be stored and programmed after a buttonclick. I am looking for the best way to store those settings for different device types, and programmed in the device and entered in by the user

Comment: Not a design pattern but I'd probably do this.

Answer (score 2):

Not a design pattern but I'd probably do this:

```
// represents a device with it's settings
public class Device
{
   public string Type { get; set;}

   public List<Setting> Settings { get; set; }
}

// represents a setting, agnostic of which device it applies to
public class Setting
{
   public string Setting { get; set; }

   public string Value { get; set; }
}

// represents mapping which devices has which settings
public class DeviceSettings
{
   public List<string> ApplicableDevices { get; set; }

   public List<Settings> ApplicableSettings { get; set; }
}
```

Don't focus on the collection types used. And I would imagine you would have more properties.

Using this design, you can define settings at run time and assign them to particular devices.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). You can encapsulate the settings in a configuration object and used it as input for the controller class. After the controller class has been configured with the proper parameters, you can just call its `execute` method which will process the data.

You can also join this with [State pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) or with [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) to switch the processing algorithm (e.g., in one state the processing may include sending the data to the device and in another receiving it from the device).

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do this (my C# is a bit rusty, so don't expect the syntax to be right):

```
class Settings
{
  Settings parent = null;
  Map<String, String> settings;
  String getSetting(String setting)
  {
    if (settings.contains(setting))
      return settings.get(setting);
    else if (parent != null)
      return parent.getSetting(setting);
    else return null;
  }
}
```

Then the common settings is the parent of each device and the common settings has no parent.

How to access / create these classes would depend on the structure of the project. A singleton containing a set of these classes (possibly in a map (`Map<String, Setting>`)) is one idea.

The nice thing about doing things this way, is that a child Settings can also optionally override a setting of it's parent.